# Can mysql query be simplified ... or is there a need for a function, procedure?

Tags: python, mysql, web.py

I am making an small program in Python and with web.py as web end. For that code I have a sql query as below. The query is needed for making a web slideshow with names and titles for scale models to be shown in that slideshow. All Bronze are te bo shown on one page, all Silver medals are to be shown on one page and all gold medals are shown separatly. 
As I have it now is that with every tick on a next button in the browser, I will get the next index of the sql query. Say index 0 from the sql query is:

```
Name    Surname    Title    Results    Class_ID    outcome
John    Doe        Test1     Bronze     1           John Doe with: Test1 Jane Doe with: Test1
```

And index 1 from the sql query is:

```
Name    Surname    Title    Results    Class_ID    outcome
Jane    Doe        Test2     Silver     1           Jane Doe with: Test2 John Doe with: Test2
```

Model Test1 from John and Jane have bronze medals and are concated with GROUP_CONCAT to get all same results from that particular class on one 'line'. Same goes for the silver medals. All gold medals are to be shown separatly. I start with Class 1 and bronze medals, after that the next index is shown and are the silver medals of Class 1, after that Gold and all that repeats for the 31 classes I have.

Question is: 
Can below query be simplified? All I have now is a query for one Class. In total there are 31 different classes, so query should be run over all 31 classes to see if there are medals awarded and if so, concat the Bronze and after that concat the Silver and show the Gold separatly. I tried to make a function in MySQL but could not get it to work...

```
SELECT naw.Name, naw.Surname, model.Title, model.Results, model.Class_ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(naw.Name, ' ',naw.Surname, ' with: ', model.Title SEPARATOR ' ') AS outcome
FROM naw
LEFT OUTER JOIN model ON model.User_ID = naw.User_ID
WHERE model.Results = 'Bronze' AND Class_ID = '1'

UNION

SELECT naw.Name, naw.Surname, model.Title, model.Results, model.Class_ID,
GROUP_CONCAT(naw.Name, ' ',naw.Surname, ' with: ', model.Title SEPARATOR ' ') AS outcome
FROM naw
LEFT OUTER JOIN model ON model.User_ID = naw.User_ID
WHERE model.Results = 'Silver' AND Class_ID = '1'

UNION

SELECT naw.Name, naw.Surname, model.Title, model.Results, model.Class_ID, model.ID
FROM naw
LEFT OUTER JOIN model ON model.User_ID = naw.User_ID
WHERE model.Results = 'Gold' AND Class_ID = '1'
```

Please feel free to ask if something is not correctly explained. My first in asking help here.

Thanks and with kind Regards,

**UPDATE - Problem solved**

Was looking in the complete wrong direction. Below solution to my question.

```
SELECT naw.*, model.*, 
CASE
    WHEN Results = "Gold" THEN 4 + naw.User_ID
    WHEN Results = "Silver" THEN 2
    WHEN Results = "Bronze" THEN 3
    ELSE 4
END AS pageCategory,
GROUP_CONCAT(naw.Name, ' ',naw.Surname, ' with: ', model.Title SEPARATOR '<br>') AS        categories
FROM naw
INNER JOIN model ON model.User_ID = naw.User_ID
INNER JOIN classes ON model.Class_ID = classes.Class_ID
WHERE
Results <> 'None'
GROUP BY
pageCategory, classes.Class_ID
ORDER BY
classes.Class_ID, FIELD(Results, 'Bronze', 'Silver', 'Gold')
```